# How to get the enabled manage displays per node type?

Tags: 8

I have an admin form and need to check if a node, e.g. article has a specific manage display enabled. How do I get the data?

Found out to get an array of all available displays in general and there is a difference between display views and view modes. May I am just searching with the wrong terms.

Comment: display and form types are both entities. You can inject the EntityTypeManager into your form and query `entity_form_display` or `entity_view_display` entities from the respective storages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this service:

**EntityDisplayRepository**

> Provides a repository for entity display objects (view modes and form
>   modes).

Example:

```
$view_modes = \Drupal::service('entity_display.repository')
  ->getViewModeOptionsByBundle('node', 'article');
```

More info: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityDisplayRepository.php/class/EntityDisplayRepository/8.2.x